# org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: unpacking field 46 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204)

Tags: jpos

I am trying to unpack an ISO 8583 message and I am getting error while trying to unpack the 46th field stating the length cannot exceed 204.
Please find my ISOmessage:

> 1200F07405C188C480000100000C1400000410114040200050007700000001320061000000111318201608071619349912090099099001200151059990648742906BANK02701214010962 ibank00000000000000003470404C0000000000000000D00000000404404129EBP123SVCT0000204PAYD00103sort|40402000|;sort2|40478000|;phone2|254716191411|;terminal_id| ibank|;transaction_type|credit_push|07RTPSNIF07RTPSNIF07RTPSNIF1301003013812000011sahalksjdls

And my parser xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">
 <!-- DOCTYPE iso8583packager SYSTEM "ISO8583_PACKAGER.dtd"
  --> 
 <!--  ISO 8583:1993 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager 
  --> 
 <isopackager>
  <isofield id="0" length="4" name="Message_Type_Indicator" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="1" length="32" name="Bitmap" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP" /> 
  <isofield id="2" length="19" name="Primary_Account_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="3" length="6" name="Processing_Code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="4" length="12" name="Amount_Transaction" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="5" length="12" name="Amount_Reconciliation" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="6" length="12" name="Amount_Cardholder_billing" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="7" length="14" name="Date_and_time_transmission" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="8" length="8" name="Amount_Cardholder_billing_fee" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="9" length="8" name="Conversion_rate_Reconciliation" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="10" length="8" name="Conversion_rate_Cardholder_billing" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="11" length="6" name="Systems_audit_trace_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="12" length="14" name="Local_transaction_time" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="13" length="4" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="14" length="4" name="Date_Expiration" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="15" length="14" name="Settlement_Date_Business_Date" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="16" length="4" name="Date_Conversion" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="17" length="4" name="Date_Capture" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="18" length="4" name="Merchant_type" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="19" length="3" name="Country_code_Acquiring_institution" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="20" length="3" name="Country_code_Primary_account_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="21" length="3" name="Country_code_Forwarding_institution" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="22" length="12" name="Point_of_service_data_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="23" length="3" name="Card_sequence_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="24" length="3" name="Function_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="25" length="4" name="Message_reason_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="26" length="4" name="Card_acceptor_business_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="27" length="1" name="Approval_code_length" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="28" length="14" name="Transaction_Fees_Amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="29" length="3" name="Reconciliation_indicator" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="30" length="24" name="Amounts_original" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="31" length="99" name="Acquirer_reference_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="32" length="11" name="Acquirer_institution_identification_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="33" length="11" name="Forwarding_institution_identification_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="34" length="28" name="Primary_account_number_extended" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="35" length="37" name="Track_2_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_FLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="36" length="104" name="Track_3_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="37" length="12" name="Retrieval_reference_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="38" length="6" name="Approval_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="39" length="3" name="Response_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="40" length="3" name="Service_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="41" length="8" name="Card_acceptor_terminal_identification" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="42" length="15" name="Card_acceptor_identification_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="43" length="99" name="Card_acceptor_name_location" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="44" length="99" name="Additional_response_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="45" length="76" name="Track_1_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="46" length="204" name="Amounts_Fees" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="47" length="999" name="Additional_data_national" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="48" length="999" name="Additional_data_private" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="49" length="3" name="Currency_code_Transaction" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="50" length="3" name="Currency_code_Reconciliation" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="51" length="3" name="Currency_code_Cardholder_billing" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="52" length="4" name="Personal_identification_number_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" /> 
  <isofield id="53" length="12" name="Security_related_control_information" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" /> 
  <isofield id="54" length="360" name="Amounts_additional" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="55" length="510" name="IC_card_system_related_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="56" length="37" name="Original_data_elements" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="57" length="3" name="Authorization_life_cycle_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="58" length="11" name="Authorizing_agent_institution_Id_Code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="59" length="999" name="Transport_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="60" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="61" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="62" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="63" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="64" length="8" name="Message_authentication_code_field" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" /> 
  <isofield id="65" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="66" length="204" name="Amounts_original_fees" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="67" length="2" name="Extended_payment_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="68" length="3" name="Country_code_receiving_institution" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="69" length="3" name="Country_code_settlement_institution" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="70" length="3" name="Country_code_authorizing_agent_Inst." class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="71" length="8" name="Message_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="72" length="999" name="Data_record" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="73" length="6" name="Transaction_Year" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="74" length="10" name="Credits_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="75" length="10" name="Credits_reversal_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="76" length="10" name="Debits_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="77" length="10" name="Debits_reversal_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="78" length="10" name="Transfer_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="79" length="10" name="Transfer_reversal_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="80" length="10" name="Inquiries_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="81" length="10" name="Authorizations_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="82" length="10" name="Inquiries_reversal_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="83" length="10" name="Payments_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="84" length="10" name="Payments_reversal_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="85" length="10" name="Fee_collections_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="86" length="16" name="Credits_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="87" length="16" name="Credits_reversal_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="88" length="16" name="Debits_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="89" length="16" name="Debits_reversal_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="90" length="10" name="Original_Data_Elements" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="91" length="3" name="Country_code_transaction_Dest._Inst." class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="92" length="3" name="Country_code_transaction_Orig._Inst." class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="93" length="11" name="Transaction_Dest._Inst._Id_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="94" length="11" name="Transaction_Orig._Inst._Id_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="95" length="99" name="Card_issuer_reference_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="96" length="999" name="Key_management_data" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY" /> 
  <isofield id="97" length="17" name="Amount_Net_reconciliation" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="98" length="25" name="Payee" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="99" length="11" name="Settlement_institution_Id_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="100" length="11" name="Receiving_institution_Id_code" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="101" length="17" name="File_name" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="102" length="28" name="Account_identification_1" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="103" length="28" name="Account_identification_2" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="104" length="100" name="Transaction_description" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="105" length="16" name="Credits_Chargeback_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="106" length="16" name="Debits_Chargeback_amount" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="107" length="10" name="Credits_Chargeback_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="108" length="10" name="Debits_Chargeback_number" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" /> 
  <isofield id="109" length="84" name="Credits_Fee_amounts" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="110" length="84" name="Debits_Fee_amounts" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="111" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="112" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="113" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="114" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="115" length="999" name="Reserved_for_ISO_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="116" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="117" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="118" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="119" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> `enter code here`
  <isofield id="120" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="121" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="122" length="999" name="Reserved_for_national_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="123" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="124" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="125" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="126" length="4000" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="127" length="999" name="Reserved_for_private_use" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR" /> 
  <isofield id="128" length="4" name="Message_authentication_code_field" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY" /> 
  </isopackager>
```

Comment: You can't  honestly expect us to parse your error message without showing us the code which created it?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I tried the following code:
package stack.examples;

```
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOPackager;
import org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager;
import org.jpos.util.Logger;
import org.jpos.util.SimpleLogListener;

public class ParserError {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException {
        String msg = "1200F07405C188C480000100000C1400000410114040200050007700000001320061000000111318201608071619349912090099099001200151059990648742906BANK02701214010962 ibank00000000000000003470404C0000000000000000D00000000404404129EBP123SVCT0000204PAYD00103sort|40402000|;sort2|40478000|;phone2|254716191411|;terminal_id| ibank|;transaction_type|credit_push|07RTPSNIF07RTPSNIF07RTPSNIF1301003013812000011sahalksjdls";
        Logger logger = new Logger();
        logger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener());
        GenericPackager pkgr = new GenericPackager("src/test/resources/packager.xml");

        ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
        m.setPackager(pkgr);
        pkgr.setLogger(logger, "packager");

        m.unpack(msg.getBytes());
    }

}
```

The problem is you have a missalignement in your parser.xml definition, it's seems strange a pan (field 2) of length 10, but it seems to be parsing ok until field 33 "BANK02" field 41 seems to be bad already. What you expect in each field? that may yield to a guess on where in the parser.xml is the problem.

The output of the previous code is as follows:

```
<log realm="packager" at="2017-01-26T12:46:35.168" lifespan="71ms">
  <unpack>
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
    <bitmap>{1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 14, 22, 24, 25, 26, 32, 33, 37, 41, 42, 46, 49, 72, 93, 94, 100, 102, 126}</bitmap>
    <unpack fld="2" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR">
      <value>1140402000</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="3" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>500077</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="4" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>000000013200</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="10" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>61000000</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="11" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>111318</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="12" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>20160807161934</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="14" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>9912</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="22" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <value>090099099001</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="24" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>200</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="25" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>1510</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="26" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC">
      <value>5999</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="32" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR">
      <value>487429</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="33" packager="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR">
      <value>BANK02</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="37" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <value>701214010962</value>
Exception in thread "main" org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 46 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204) unpacking field=46, consumed=172
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:334)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at stack.examples.ParserError.main(ParserError.java:22)
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="41" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <value> ibank00</value>
    </unpack>
    <unpack fld="42" packager="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR">
      <value>000000000000003</value>
    </unpack>
    error unpacking field 46 consumed=172
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 46
      <iso-exception>
        Field length 470 too long. Max: 204
        org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOStringFieldPackager.unpack(ISOStringFieldPackager.java:179)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:305)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at stack.examples.ParserError.main(ParserError.java:22)
      </iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 46 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOStringFieldPackager.unpack(ISOStringFieldPackager.java:187)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:305)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at stack.examples.ParserError.main(ParserError.java:22)
Nested:org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOStringFieldPackager.unpack(ISOStringFieldPackager.java:179)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:305)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at stack.examples.ParserError.main(ParserError.java:22)
    </iso-exception>
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 46 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204) unpacking field=46, consumed=172
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 46 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 470 too long. Max: 204) unpacking field=46, consumed=172
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:334)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at stack.examples.ParserError.main(ParserError.java:22)
    </iso-exception>
  </unpack>
</log>
```